# i need fixed marker in screen center with Flutter_map package

Tags: flutter

I need a fixed marker in the middle of the page that the user can touch to give me the point description of that place

I use Flutter_Map package

Sample [This is the demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtpYL.gif)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far.

Comment: As an alternative, flutter_map offers an `onTap` callback that returns the position of the tap as LatLng().